# Google is scanning a query string I don't want it to

Tags: google-search

Google is scanning my website on Google including a query string I don't want it to scan.
For example: Their is a page - "/name.html" and in the URL it has a query string - "/name.html?qs=1". I don't want Google to include "?qs=1" in their index, because this query string isn't necessary and it'll create a lot of duplicates and trash when searching for my website on Google.

How can I disable Google's ability to index this query string and delete pages that had already indexed like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) to do this.

Here is an example :

```
user-agent: *
disallow: /name.html?
```

This will block any call to name.html with a query string, but will index your name.html.

There is also this version :

```
user-agent: *
disallow: /name.html?qs=
```

This will block any call to name.html with the parameter "qs" contained in your query string, but will index anything else.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make a robots.txt file in the root of your website.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: qs

# Googlebot allows regex in its syntax
User-Agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /*?qs*
```

Comment: I would recommend caution at root level.